upgrade Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) versions
Hellow,Due to a problem I re-downloaded and installed Flutter and Android Studio, and as a result, an error appeared with me," This is likely due to a known bug in Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) versions less than 8.2.1, this error when i make any addition to a file(pubspec.uaml)
error
error
**build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


**gradle-warpper-prperties
**
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip


downloaded older version (android studio)
